# ¿Cómo obtener el navegador y versión desde el controller en C# asp-net-core 2.2?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Estoy intentando obtener el navegador y la versión de éste, solamente para registrar en un log, desde donde se están generando los eventos.

He buscado por la red y lo que he encontrado es todo similar a esto

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httprequest.browser?view=netframework-4.8&viewFallbackFrom=netcore-2.2

Pero la palabra reservada **"HttpBrowserCapabilities"**, no la reconoce mi proyecto.

¿Alguna otra idea de cómo realizar eso?

> Gravedad   Código  Descripción Proyecto    Archivo Línea   Estado suprimido
>   Error   CS0246  El nombre del tipo o del espacio de nombres 'HttpBrowserCapabilities' no se encontró. Seguridad C:\Users\M\Controllers\HomeController.cs    26  Activo

¿falta una directiva using o una referencia de ensamblado?

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Lo que estas viendo es justamente para .net 4.8, no para net.core.

Comment: De acuerdo. Gracias.
Lo solvente con ayuda de esta información.
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/How-to-get-OS-and-browser-c007dbf7/sourcecode?fileId=171698&pathId=2106003852

Comment: Que bueno que encontraste una respuesta!! porque, justamente, no lo agregas como respuesta?

Answer (score 0):

Lo solvente con ayuda de esta información.

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/How-to-get-OS-and-browser-c007dbf7/sourcecode?fileId=171698&pathId=2106003852